# How to close file so that it can be used by other processor?

Tags: file, parallel-processing, multiprocessor

I'm trying to remove file text.pckl with command os.remove('text.pckl'). I have created the file by other processor and I get error:

WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'text.pckl'

How can I close the file so that it is not anymore used by the processor? So far I have use file.close() command.

Answer (score 0):

try following:

```
os.close('text.pckl')
```

Comment: But now I can't dump my pickle into text.pckl. To use os.close('text.pckl') I have to open file by os.open (?) I don't know how to dump pickle to that kind of file. I usually create pickle files by file = open('file.pckl', 'wb').